# Paginação com angular e javascript emitindo eventos sempre retorna a mesma página

Tags: javascript, angular

Estou estudando javascript e angular agora, eu tenho um componente de paginação com o seguinte HTML:

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" (click)="goPrevious()" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a
        class="page-link"
        routerLinkActive="active"
        [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
        (click)="goToPage($event.target.value)"
        >{{ currentPage }}</a
      >
    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" (click)="goToPage($event.target.value)">{{
        currentPage + 1
      }}</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" (click)="goToPage($event.target.value)">{{
        currentPage + 2
      }}</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="goToPage($event.target.value)">{{
        currentPage + 3
      }}</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" (click)="goToPage($event.target.value)">{{
        currentPage + 4
      }}</a>
    </li>

    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" (click)="goNext()">Next</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

E eu tenho um componente TS com a seguintes funções

```
@Output() paginate = new EventEmitter<number>();
currentPage = 0;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { this.currentPage = 1; }

  goNext() {this.currentPage += 5; }

  goPrevious = () =>  this.currentPage > 1 ? this.currentPage -= 5 : null;

  goToPage($event: any) {
    $event = this.currentPage;
    this.paginate.emit($event);
    console.log(this.currentPage);
  }
```

Quando eu clico nos números, por exemplo 4, ele sempre me retorna CurrentPage como 1. Aonde estou errando ?

Comment: Eu tentei esse já, não deu.

Comment: pq vc não faz: (click)="goToPage(currentPage + 1)"

Comment: já tentei assim também, mas não deu certo.

Comment: Não sei explicar direito, mas ele sempre devolve a primeira página.

Comment: Faz assim:  (click)="goToPage(currentPage + 1)" que da certo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que eu sempre estava passando a currentPage, ao invés do valor do evento. Corrigi deixando da seguinte forma. 
Então corrigir o método da seguinte forma:

```
goToPage($event: any) {
    this.paginate.emit($event.target.innerText);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Elementos 'a' não tem value

```
(click)="goToPage(currentPage + 1)"
```

ts:

```
 goToPage($event: any) {
    this.currentPage=$event;
    this.paginate.emit($event);
    console.log(this.currentPage);
  }
```